Update date difference from columns of same table
I have a table with 4 columns - FileName, CreatedDate,TodayDate, DifferenceDays.
Every day i run a perl script that adds new files that are created to the database (using INSERT). This part of script works fine.
For the old files that are already in the DB, i need to update the columns TodayDate with trunc(SYSDATE) and DifferenceDays with days difference between TodayDate and CreatedDate.
I tried the below query but it only updates the TodayDate but not the DifferenceDays:
UPDATE fileDB
SET TodayDate = trunc(SYSDATE),
    DifferenceDays = TodayDate - CreatedDate
WHERE trunc(TodayDate) != trunc(SYSDATE)

Please help me identify issue with my query.

If I understand this correctly you demand that all rows in the table have the same date. This sounds like a bad idea. Store the date only once (in a separate table) instead. I further understand that you want to ensure DifferenceDays is always TodayDate - CreatedDate. In that case it is a bad idea to store it, because that would be redundant. You can always calculate this difference on-the-fly. Never store data redundantly in a database if not really necessary. You can use a generated column or a view for convenience, if you want to.

It seems that CreatedDate differs, as new rows are added; TodaysDate needs to be the same but as that's based on sysdate there's no point storing that either, here or in a separate table. And as that's non-deterministic it can't be a virtual column so... a view certainly seems the sensible choice.

When you do this:
UPDATE fileDB
SET TodayDate = trunc(SYSDATE),
    DifferenceDays = TodayDate - CreatedDate
WHERE trunc(TodayDate) != trunc(SYSDATE)

the calculation TodayDate - CreatedDate is using the current value of TodayDate, not the value it's being set to in this same statement.
The simplest thing to do here is just repeat the trunc():
UPDATE fileDB
SET TodayDate = trunc(SYSDATE),
    DifferenceDays = trunc(SYSDATE) - CreatedDate
WHERE trunc(TodayDate) != trunc(SYSDATE)

In general, applying a function to a column in a filter, as you are with
WHERE trunc(TodayDate) != trunc(SYSDATE)

will prevent a plain index on that column being used. It's usually better to leave the value as it is if you can, e.g. assuming there are no dates in the future:
WHERE TodayDate < trunc(SYSDATE)

Here you seem to be updating nearly all your records, so an index wouldn't be used anyway.
This seems like an odd way to maintain your data. It would be a lot less work (and less storage) to only have the CreatedDate column in the table, and then generate the other two columns as you query the table; possibly with a view defined to simplify that.

Thanks for the answer! This table is being used by another module that just can read the table and cannot perform any kind of calculation on the data. Hence i am forced to do all the calculations and update the same in the table itself.

Well, you could rename this table and have a view with the original name that the other module queries instead. Your insert could even still refer to it if needed, with an instead-of trigger. Anyway, this just doesn't seem very sensible to me, but if you're stuck with it I can only sympathise.

Rather than storing columns that become out-dated every day and need to be recalculated. Instead, drop those columns and generate the values dynamically when you display the data (either by modifying the SELECT query used to access the table or by creating a view and SELECTing from that).
For example, if you have the table:
CREATE TABLE filedb (FileName, CreatedDate, TodayDate, DifferenceDays) AS
  WITH data (filename, createddate) AS (
    SELECT 'A', DATE '1970-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'B', DATE '1980-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'C', DATE '1990-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'D', DATE '2000-01-01' FROM DUAL
  )
  SELECT filename, createddate, TRUNC(SYSDATE), TRUNC(SYSDATE) - createddate
  FROM   data;

Then you can drop the columns that should be dynamically generated:
ALTER TABLE filedb DROP COLUMN TodayDate;
ALTER TABLE filedb DROP COLUMN DifferenceDays;

and create a view:
CREATE VIEW filedb_view (FileName, CreatedDate, TodayDate, DifferenceDays) AS
SELECT filename, createddate, TRUNC(SYSDATE), TRUNC(SYSDATE) - createddate
FROM   filedb;

Then you can query the view:
SELECT * FROM filedb_view

and today it will output:



FILENAME
CREATEDDATE
TODAYDATE
DIFFERENCEDAYS




A
1970-01-01 00:00:00
2024-06-11 00:00:00
19885


B
1980-01-01 00:00:00
2024-06-11 00:00:00
16233


C
1990-01-01 00:00:00
2024-06-11 00:00:00
12580


D
2000-01-01 00:00:00
2024-06-11 00:00:00
8928



Tomorrow it will update to tomorrow's date and increase the differences and you will not need to perform daily UPDATEs any more.
fiddle
